# Does Kanon enjoy figure skating?

Tags: g-senjou-no-maou

In G-Senjou no Maou, Kanon is a world-class figure skater. However, at different points in the story, when asked if she enjoys figure skating, she speaks ambiguously or dodges the question. It's implied at times that she is only doing it because her mother wants her to, but at other times she seems to like it.

What are Kanon's real feelings about figure skating? Is she continuing to pursue it for herself or for the interests of others?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From an early age, Kanon disliked skating and found it boring. She was only doing it because her mother wanted her to and/or forced her to do it.

[image: Kanon: Skating is so boring. ... Winning isn't fun.]

However, her mother encourages her to stick with figure skating until she can truly understand the joy that it brings.

[image: Ikuko: Then why not stick with it until you discover what it means?]

As you progress through Kanon's route, she slowly realizes that since skating has been her whole life, it has also greatly shaped her life. Thanks to her ability in skating, she was able to finally meet her father.

[image: ... She was relieved to know that she, too, had a father. For the first time, she felt glad she started skating.]

There was another scene where she spends Christmas Eve at a home for the elderly. Most of the people living there were lonely since they hadn't seen their children for so long, and Kanon was genuinely glad that she, a well-known figure skater, could brighten their Christmas Eve just a little bit.

Eventually, in her Good End, Kanon admits that she loves skating due to all of the life occurrences and experiences that it has brought her.

[image: Kanon: I love it.]

In her next performance after this scene, she dazzles the crowd with her ability and emotion to the point that everyone is cheering for her, even despite the fact her poor attitude in a previous performance made everyone dislike her. The genuine reaction from the audience, as well as the support she receives from her friends and mother, allow her to finally understand her mother's advice from many years ago.

[image: She finally understood.]

[image: Kanon was happy that she kept skating.]